# How to exactly determine the position and sign in vector quantity like displacement?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics, coordinate-systems, vectors, displacement

I want to know how to determine the sign. I used opposite sign my answer was 32 m. This is is wrong because in displacement sign is required for direction. This is crucial otherwise all my solutions I have done so far are incorrect.

For example here in the book it is opposite, and the bug is resting near wall but in my case it is opposite.

[image]

[image]

Problem is even if I try to specify the direction the answer sheet still checking team uses answer key to verify. So how can I be sure. Is there any information I am missing the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that you have chosen a unit vector, $\hat {\mathbf w}$ that points along the ruler towards the wall. In that case you should have found the resultant displacement to be +32 cm $\hat {\mathbf w}$ and the fly's final position to be at the 68 cm mark.

As long as you have these answers, I wouldn't worry. You clearly know the Physics. The choice of direction for your unit vector is arbitrary, though I prefer the choice made in the book: the unit vector points in the direction in which the numbers on the ruler increase. But that's just a personal preference.

Comment: I see. 200 is touching floor. Your point makes sense, choosing this way would ease calculations. Being this so easy to solve, hope I wont get downvotes :P. Thanks for your answer

Comment: Yes, sometimes questions on basic Physics do get downvoted, even if they are conceptual in character – like yours. But you can rise above such a thing!